# How to set keyboard key sizes to match icons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I have a customized keyboard which uses images to represent the keys. I'm currently having a problem with the key sizes, as the images have a set size. After I set the `keyIcon`, there are blank spaces on the side since the `keyWidth` that was set does not match the image. Here is what it looks like: http://s4.postimg.org/kyvpi86kd/Screenshot_2013_05_01_10_12_06.png

This is the code that I use to setup my keyboard within my application:

```
KeyboardView keyboardView = (KeyboardView)view.findViewById(R.id.keyboardView);
Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard(getActivity(), R.xml.key_pin_pad);
```

Where `R.xml.key_pin_pad` is the xml file used to populate the keyboard.

Is there a way to emulates LinearLayouts for keyboard xmls? I would really like to be able to do something like `layout_width="wrap_content"` instead of manipulating the pixel width to see if the keys fit.

**Edit:**

I was able to make the keys fit in place by setting the key backgrounds in the XML of the KeyboardView:

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
...
    android:keyBackground="@drawable/keypad_1"/>
```

If there is no `keyIcon` set, then the image fits exactly as I'd like for it to. Unfortunately, every one of my keys has its own drawable, so this is setting the background of every key to "1". Does anyone know of a way to generalize the setting of the backgrounds? Manually setting the `keyBackground` of the keys of `R.xml.key_pin_pad` show nothing for some reason.

Comment: shouldn't the "keyBackground" be a global background, for each of the keys, and if you wish to set it for a specific one, you use it where you need it?

Comment: Yes, the keyBackground is a global background for the keys, I was just using keypad_1 drawable as an example since I don't yet have a blank background drawable. What I noticed was that there is no simple way to set individual keyBackgrounds, as setting it in the keyboard .xml does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this further, I have decided that the simplest method here is to just change the icon images.

Instead of having key icons consisting of a number/background, The icons will just be numbers with transparent backgrounds and a separate, number-less background drawable will be used in place of the `KeyboardView` `keyBackground`.